# Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/curve'

Tags: overleaf, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

This is code generated from Quiver. Overleaf doesn't like the `curve` command for some reason. It gives the error message in the title.

```
\begin{tikzcd}
    && {(AB)C} \\
    & {A(BC)} \\
    AB && {(AB)C}
    \arrow["{h_2}"', dashed, from=1-3, to=2-2]
    \arrow["{f_1}"', from=2-2, to=3-1]
    \arrow["h", from=1-3, to=3-3]
    \arrow["{f_1 \circ h_2}"', curve={height=30pt}, from=1-3, to=3-1]
    \arrow["{p_{AB}}", from=3-3, to=3-1]
\end{tikzcd}
```

It shows up fine on Quiver

[image]

But looks like this when I put it in Overleaf

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess Overleaf doesn't like it because it doesn't exist in TikZ/`tikz-cd`. From a [quick search in the Quiver source code](https://github.com/varkor/quiver/search?q=curve) it appears that Quiver has a [small LaTeX package](https://github.com/varkor/quiver/blob/aabd442f6e0baefb7bb08a8024683f876bb95a7f/src/quiver.sty#L25) which defines this style. So you need to upload `quiver.sty` to your Overleaf project, and have `\usepackage{quiver}` in the preamble of your document.

Comment: Thanks so much!